# GStreamer rtph265pay/rtph265depay does not work if rtph265pay started before rtph265depay

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

Given two GStreamer pipelines:

#### Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc do-timestamp=true pattern=snow ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! x265enc ! h265parse ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5801
```

#### Receiver

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5801 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H265 ! rtph265depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink sync=false
```

If I start the `Receiver` first, the pipeline works fine. If I start the `Sender` first, the receiver pipeline never actually starts showing any output. It does print the following to the terminal:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, encoding-name=(string)H265, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH265Depay:rtph265depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, encoding-name=(string)H265, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000
```

Any ideas to why this happens? I am assuming there is some form of "start" packet sent at the beginning of the stream that the receiver needs to be "awake" for, but this is purely based on intuition, not any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I would have found it if I read the documentation of `rtph265pay`. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp/rtph265pay.html?gi-language=c

There is a parameter called `config-interval`, which "Send VPS, SPS and PPS Insertion Interval in seconds". This parameter is initially 0, which means it likely only sends it at the beginning of the stream and never again. Setting this value to a positive number makes the receiver able to start reading the stream every time this data is sent. For my application, a value of 1s works great.